# ListView not updating when adding new items, but when removing

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection, updatesourcetrigger

Okay guys, I'm pretty new to C# and struggling with UpdateSourceTriggers of ListViews. It's working when I'm deleting something, but it's not when I'm adding something new. And it's strange, because I can hover the ListView and see that something has been added, but it's not showing the name and the price.

This is my code:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="orders" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOrderList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuRemove}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Height="800" 
          Style="{StaticResource CustomListViewStyle}" >
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>

<!--
It's working with this one
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Width="400" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Preis" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MenuId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Width="80" />-->
<!--Not with this-->
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Menu.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                      Width="400" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Preis" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Menu.Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                      Width="80" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

```cs
class OrderViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> AllMenus { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
    public ObservableCollection<Category> AllCategories { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    public ObservableCollection<Order> AllOrders { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> TemporaryMenus { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Order> _SelectedOrderList;
    public ObservableCollection<Order> SelectedOrderList
    {
        get { return _SelectedOrderList; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedOrderList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOrderList));
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Menu> _FilteredMenus;
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> FilteredMenus
    {
        get { return _FilteredMenus; }
        set
        {
            _FilteredMenus = value;
            TemporaryMenus = new ObservableCollection<Menu>(
                AllMenus.Where(menu => menu.CategoryId.Equals(SelectedCategory.Id))
            );
            FilteredMenus.Clear();
            foreach (var menu in TemporaryMenus)
            {
                FilteredMenus.Add(menu);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredMenus));
        }
    }
    private Category _SelectedCategory;
    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _SelectedCategory; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            FilteredMenus = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
        }
    }
    private Menu _SelectedMenuAdd;
    public Menu SelectedMenuAdd
    {
        get { return _SelectedMenuAdd; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedMenuAdd = value;
            if (SelectedMenuAdd != null)
            {
                Order newOrder = new Order
                {
                    MenuId = SelectedMenuAdd.Id,
                    TableId = Global.TableParameter,
                    WaiterId = 1,
                    Printstatus = 1,
                    Starttime = DateTime.Now
                };
                SelectedOrderList.Add(newOrder);
                using (var db = new BonGoContext())
                {
                    db.Add(newOrder);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                SelectedMenuAdd = null;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMenuAdd));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOrderList));
        }
    }
    private Order _SelectedMenuRemove;
    public Order SelectedMenuRemove
    {
        get { return _SelectedMenuRemove; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedMenuRemove = value;
            if (SelectedMenuRemove != null)
            {
                Order orderToRemove = SelectedOrderList.FirstOrDefault(
                    order => order.Id == SelectedMenuRemove.Id
                );
                if (orderToRemove != null)
                {
                    SelectedOrderList.Remove(orderToRemove);
                    using (var db = new BonGoContext())
                    {
                        db.Orders.Remove(orderToRemove);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMenuRemove));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOrderList));
        }
    }

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = new BonGoContext())
        {
            AllMenus = new ObservableCollection<Menu>(
                db.Menus.Select(
                    menu =>
                        new Menu
                        {
                            Id = menu.Id,
                            Name = menu.Name,
                            Price = Math.Round(menu.Price, 2),
                            CategoryId = menu.CategoryId
                        }
                )
            );
            AllCategories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(
                db.Categories.Select(
                    category => new Category { Id = category.Id, Name = category.Name }
                )
            );
            AllOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(
                db.Orders.Select(
                    order =>
                        new Order
                        {
                            Id = order.Id,
                            MenuId = order.MenuId,
                            Menu = order.Menu,
                            TableId = order.TableId,
                            WaiterId = order.WaiterId,
                            Printstatus = order.Printstatus,
                            Starttime = order.Starttime,
                            Endtime = order.Endtime,
                            Dailyclosing = order.Dailyclosing
                        }
                )
            );
        }
        SelectedOrderList = new ObservableCollection<Order>(
            AllOrders.Where(order => order.TableId == Global.TableParameter)
        );
        SelectedCategory = AllCategories.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with UpdateSourceTrigger, which only affects TwoWay and OneWayToSource Bindings. The ItemsSource Binding is inherently OneWay. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Besides that, have you used the debugger to check if `SelectedOrderList.Add` is ever called at all? Please also format your code property. It is impossible to read without any indentation.

Comment: Yes, the SelectedOrderList.Add is called and it also adds the orders to the list properly. As I stated, I also can see in the ListView that something has been added by hovering the mouse over it, but it doesn't show any names. It just show names if I change the view to something else and then back to the ListView from the code.

Thank you for formatting my code, somehow this has been lost in the copy&paste process.

Comment: As a note, it is pointless to call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOrderList))` outside the setter of the SelectedOrderList property. Any changes to the collection are notified by the ObservableCollection. The value of the SelectedOrderList property itself does not change when you add or remove items. The property should be read-only anyway. It is apparently only once set in the view model constructor.

Comment: You are right. I tried different solutions to achieve the ListView updating properly and this is one (of maybe a couple) leftovers. Thank you for your feedback. Do you have any solution to my problem? It appears that {Binding Menu.Name} and {Binding Menu.Price} doesn't work like it should, beccause the SelectedOrderList and the ListView gets updated, it's just the names of the newly added items are missing and just shows blank.

Comment: No idea how your code is supposed to work, but you do apparently not initialize a new Order's Menu property before calling `SelectedOrderList.Add(newOrder)`.